# The difference between "Closed" and "On Hold"

Tags: discussion, support, closed-questions, on-hold

I keep on seeing questions either "put on hold" or "closed" by the same thing, like for instance here a question has been "put on hold" for being off-topic:

[image: on hold off-topic]

And here is a question which has been "closed" for being off-topic:

[image: closed off-topic]

So what is the difference then between a question being "closed" and "put on hold"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Closed questions are labeled as being "on hold" for the first 5 days.

The wording change was made to try to make question authors more likely to try to improve their questions when closed, rather than thinking that a question being closed was an irreversible state.